# Boundary check for triple integral using substitution method

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

> Please check my substitution for this integral,
> $$\iiint _V\left(z\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z,$$
> where $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 3$, $z\ge 1$.

I am not sure how to do the correct substitution, this is how I've done it since $x^2+y^2+z^2\le 3$ its a sphere with the center in origin and radius $\sqrt{3}$:

$T:x=rsin\phi cos\theta ,\:y=rsin\phi sin\theta \:,\:z=rcos\theta \:$

where $\theta \in \left[0,2\pi \right]$, and $0\le r\le \sqrt{3}$ , $\left|Jt\right|=r^2sin\phi \:$

I am not sure if I found the correct boundary for r and what is the boundary for $\phi$. I plan to integrate in the following order $\mathrm{d}r$ $\mathrm{d}\phi$ $\mathrm{d}\theta$ . No need to evaluate, I just want to find out the boundary for $\phi$ and check if the one for r is correct.

Comment: Have you considered using cylindrical coordinates instead since that seems like it might be easier?

Comment: Am I allowed to use them when I have a sphere? @JohnOmielan 
yes i have tried this way: $1\le h\le \sqrt{3-x^2-y^2}$ , $1\le r\le \sqrt{3}$ and same $\theta$ is it correct? Sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Regarding being "allowed", you can use any well defined coordinate system. For example, you can use standard Cartesian coordinates for a sphere, but it makes solving the integral fairly messy. Instead, the key issue is which one makes it easiest & simplest to solve the integral. As for the way you tried it, there are several mistakes. Consider the volume being the sum of horizontal circles with heights of $dz$. The $z$ component goes from $1$ to its maximum of $\sqrt{3}$. The $r^2 = x^2+y^2$ component goes from $0$ to $3 - z^2$, so $0 \le r \le \sqrt{3-z^2}$. The $\theta$ remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on how you have defined x and y in spherical coordinates, you have a typo in z, $z = \rho \cos\phi$ and not $\rho \cos\theta$.

Also the lower limit of $\rho$ is not zero. It is defined by $z = 1$.

$z = 1 \implies \rho \cos\phi = 1$ so $\rho = \sec \phi$.

At intersection of plane $z = 1$ and surface of the sphere, $\rho = \sqrt3, z = 1$.

So $z = 1 = \sqrt3 \cos\phi \implies \phi = \arccos {\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)}$

So limits are, $ \ \sec \phi \leq \rho \leq \sqrt3, 0 \leq \phi \leq \arccos {\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}\right)}, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

The order of integral is $d\rho$ first and then $d\phi, d\theta$.

In cylindrical coordinates, if we are going in the order $dr \ dz \ d\theta$,

$0 \leq r \leq \sqrt{3-z^2}, 1 \leq z \leq \sqrt3, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I see cylindrical coordinates it's much easier indeed

Comment: Yes when you are working with sphere, it is usually easier to work with spherical coordinates but if it is intersection with a plane, which is the case here, cylindrical coordinates is easier.

Comment: Are you aware of https://www.geogebra.org/3d? It will help you visualize surfaces.

Comment: Oh no, I didn't know about it, thanks this should make my life easier actually. I'll try to learn to use it properly!